# .NET WooRestAPI (WooCommerce) Get All Orders

Tags: c#, asynchronous, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using [WooCommerce.NET](https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET) wrapper class to communicate to WooCommerce API v2. I am trying to `GetAll()` the orders but it has a limit on returning 10 per page.

This is what I have so far:

```
try
{
    WooRestAPI rest = new WooRestAPI(baseUrl, key, secret);
    WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
    var getOrders = await wc.Order.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "page", "1" },
        { "per_page", "50" } }); 
    orders = ExtractWooData(getOrders);
    WriteToConsole(orders);
    WriteToFile(orders, outputPath);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

The `new Dictionary<string, string>()` is the params available from [WooRestAPI docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#list-all-orders).

I've tried looking at the `wc` object to see if I can somehow query for pages but it doesn't seem to have any property related to it.

This would also be an `async` Azure Function if that is at all relevant. How would I build up the pages so that it returns all of the Order data and not just 1 page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I do a forever `while` loop adding 1 each time to the page number. If the `wc.Order.GetAll()` returns a count less than the `per_page` limit extract the data and `break` out of the loop (means its the last call), otherwise extract the data and increment `page` #:

```
try 
{
    WooRestAPI rest = new WooRestAPI(baseUrl, key, secret);
    WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
    int pageNum = 1;
    while (true) 
    {
        var page = pageNum.ToString();
        var getOrders = await wc.Order.GetAll(new Dictionary < string, string > () {
                {
                    "page", page
                }, {
                    "per_page", "100"
                }
        });
        if (getOrders.Count < 100) 
        {
            ExtractWooData(getOrders);
            break;
        } 
        else 
        {
            ExtractWooData(getOrders);
            pageNum++;
        }
    }
    WriteToConsole(orders);
    WriteToFile(orders, outputPath);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```